# netStream with groupSpecifier not sending handler, FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, soundcloud-stratus

I have a simple video/chat application built in FLEX. I've created a groupSpecifier, netGroup and a NetStream for the different functionalities.

**NetGroup** is mainly used for the messaging (Posting) and keeping track of the users who enter.

**NetStream** is (or would be used) to control some functions like "start video, stop video" for everyone under the same group.

The most important functions I will post on here. The first is setupGroup.

```
private function setupGroup():void{
    var groupspec:GroupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier("vid"+GROUP_ID+"_sid_"+SESSION_ID);
    groupspec.serverChannelEnabled = true;
    groupspec.postingEnabled = true;
    groupspec.multicastEnabled = true;
    groupspec.ipMulticastMemberUpdatesEnabled = true;

    trace("Groupspec: "+groupspec.groupspecWithoutAuthorizations());

    netGroup = new NetGroup(nc,groupspec.groupspecWithoutAuthorizations());
    netGroup.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatus);

    netVideo = new NetStream(nc,groupspec.groupspecWithoutAuthorizations());
    netVideo.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatus);

    user = "user"+Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
}
```

The second is sendMessage

```
private function sendMessage():void{

    var message:Object = new Object();
    message.sender = netGroup.convertPeerIDToGroupAddress(nc.nearID);
    message.user = txtUser.text;
    message.text = txtMessage.text;

    netGroup.post(message);
    receiveMessage(message);

    txtMessage.text = "";
}
```

And then startVideo

```
private function startVideo():void{
    netVideo.send("publishVideo");
    ns.togglePause();
}
```

There is another function called "publishVideo" which I hope would be called for the rest of the members in the group, but this is not happening.  Most of this code is straight from the example Tom has provided from http://www.flashrealtime.com. Any help / suggestions would be appreciated!

p.s. I am not using group object replication because of the latency.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is prosaically simple.

You need to start video with:

```
netVideo.publish("channel");
```

`NetStream.send()` is for invoking callback method on receiver `NetStream.client` object.

http://www.flashrealtime.com/multicast-explained-flash-101-p2p/